# How to upload a local repository to Github

Tags: git, github

I am quite new to Git/Github.
I am trying to upload my program / website to Github, so I can upload it to Heroku.

I tried a ton of different things, and I am stuck with this for over a week...
As far as I know the way to do it is:

```
git init

git add .

git commit -m 'initial commit
```

the result I get is:

`git init` > `Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/username/test/website/.git/`

`git add .` > `error: 'website/' does not have a commit checked out fatal: adding files failed`

`git commit -m 'initial commit` >

```
Untracked files:

  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    website/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

What else can I do to set my website to Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/username/test/website/.git/",

It looks like you already have a local git repository on your computer. Next step is to create repository in the github, get the https link and do

```
git remote add origin <your repository https url>
git add .
git commit -m "intializing project"
git push origin <your branch name, ex. master>
```

Comment: I tried "git remote add origin https://github.com/benaiahdejong/website.git", but as response I get: "error: remote origin already exists." So I guess I already have a origin...

Comment: Yes, that means you already have an origin. 
Try ```git remote -v ``` to see remotes you have

Comment: website https://github.com/user/website (fetch)
-
website https://github.com/user/website (push)
-
origin https://github.com/user/website (fetch)
-
origin https://github.com/user/website (push)

Comment: wait, is the url matches with your repository https url?

Comment: Oh, no it doesn't...

Comment: Now it does, I fixed it with 'git remote add origin https://github.com/user/website.git'

Comment: Ooh cool, now you can push it to your github repository by git push origin <your branch name>

Comment: how can I see in which branch I am?

Comment: type git branch

Comment: I don't get a response when I type that, could that mean I am working without a branch?

Comment: Hmm, try git push origin master then

Comment: Now I get 'error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/website.git''

Comment: @B.deJong, I'm confused. Isn't your repository https url is " github.com/benaiahdejong/website.git" ?

Comment: you are right, I changed it to make it for everyone more easy to see

Comment: website.git is also called different, but it is a website

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a local git repository on your computer you need to set the remotes to the remote git repository such as:

```
git remote add origin <link here>
```

Then you need to stage the changes:

```
git add .

git commit -m "Initial commit"

git push
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First log in to GitHub and create a repository with the same name as what you want to push in Github.
   Repository name = Project name.
2. Then go to the terminal of your project, cd (your project name) and run the following command one by one.[seems you are not at the root of your project]
   [image: public/private repo.]

```
echo "# (your project name)" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
... ...
git remote add origin https://github.com/Here will be your github acc. name/(Your Repository name = Project name). git
git push -u origin main
```

- If you clone from another repo then instead of `remote add origin` `remote set-url` https.. do rest as usual.

Comment: for "git push -u origin main" I get the response "remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/user/website/'"

Comment: sorry, write command along your github instructions. That was for my repo!